# Why is difference_type part of std::weakly_incrementable concept?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to find out the significance of the `difference_type` member for the satisfaction of [`std::weakly_incrementable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/weakly_incrementable) concept. I'm currently defining a class satisfying `std::output_iterator` and have nothing in the domain to attach this type to (and struggling to find a use case for it).

I've tracked the root to [n3351 paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3351.pdf) and yet haven't found the actual reason there. Why did the commitee choose to put it this place in the hierarchy instead of `std::input_iterator` for example?

Comment: What's `difference_type`? Basically, were the iterator to have `-` operator that computes number of `++` needed to get from iterator to another then it would return `difference_type`. You just let it be `std::ptrdiff_t` or just large enough signed integer.

Comment: There are many range iterator operations in the standard that need to use `iter_difference_t<I>`, where `I` can be an `output_iterator`.

Comment: Related: [How to handle iterator::difference_type when you have no way of measuring the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695349/how-to-handle-iteratordifference-type-when-you-have-no-way-of-measuring-the-di)

Answer (score 2):

It's used by [`ranges::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ranges/advance) et.al.

For an output iterator who's `++` is a no-op, it's fine to define it as whichever signed integer type you like. I'd recommend `std::ptrdiff_t`. See also: [`std::ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator)`::difference_type`

Comment: Meaning: put `using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t` in your iterator.