How to write custom forward range iterator working with C++20 ranges
My original question
How can I write a C++ class that works with C++20 std::ranges library?
Origin of my problem
I tried to write a facade class with iterators in C++. But my compiler (clang++18) told me that requirements are not met and the deepest unmet requirement is: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/ranges:946:30: note: because '__adaptor::__is_range_adaptor_closure_fn(__t, __t)' would be invalid: no matching function for call to '__is_range_adaptor_closure_fn'.
My journey towards solving this problem so far
I read through several SO post including:

How to make my custom type to work with "range-based for loops"?
Creating an Iterator with C++20 Concepts for custom container
What is the difference between std::ranges::begin and std::begin?
What am I missing in my custom std::ranges iterator?

before I finally ended up here:
How to support range adaptors in custom container?
My new questions
While reading the accepted answer of bolov on that last post, several new questions arose at my side:

Why does the Iterator need to be default constructable? In my current implementation
this is an issue because it contains const references to large objects. (That might be resolvable, but if one should and how are different questions.)
Related: Why do iterators need to be default-constructible
Why does one need the difference_type if the aim is a std::forward_iterator without an implementation of operator-- and operator-?
Related: How to handle iterator::difference_type when you have no way of measuring the difference?

Example
The following is a simplifyed example of my facade class.
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_set>

using Set = std::unordered_set<std::ptrdiff_t>;

class MyFacadeClass {
private:
  class Iterator {
  public:
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type        = std::ptrdiff_t;

    Iterator(const std::ptrdiff_t self,
             const Set& a,
             const Set& b,
             const Set::const_iterator it,
             const bool inB = false) :
      pSelf(self),
      pA(a),
      pB(b),
      pIt(it),
      pInB(inB) {}

    std::ptrdiff_t operator*() const { return *pIt; }

    bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) const { return pIt != other.pIt; }

    Iterator& operator++() {
        if (pInB) {
          ++pIt;
          return *this;
        }
        else {
          do {
            ++pIt;
            if (pIt == pA.end()) {
              pIt        = pB.begin();
              pInB = true;
              return *this;
            }
          } while (*pIt == pSelf);
          return *this;
        }
      }


  private:
    const std::ptrdiff_t pSelf;
    const Set& pA;
    const Set& pB;
    Set::const_iterator pIt;
    bool pInB;
  };

  static_assert(std::forward_iterator<Iterator>);

public:
  Iterator begin() const { return Iterator(self, pA, pB, pA.begin()); }
  Iterator end() const { return Iterator(self, pA, pB, pB.end()); }

private:
  const std::ptrdiff_t self;
  const Set& pA;
  const Set& pB;
};


Goal
It would be nice to use c++ syntax like

for(const std::ptrdiff_t& member : myClass | std::views::filter(CONDITION)) {

}

Here we pretend myClass is of Type const MyFacadeClass defined earlier in the code.
Clarification of the listed questions would be nice. Thanks in advance!

Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832492/why-do-iterators-need-to-be-default-constructible and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695349/how-to-handle-iteratordifference-type-when-you-have-no-way-of-measuring-the-di

Check cppreference. Comparable value-initialized iterators and double pass guarantee seems to, in a sense, answer both your questions. Even if they don't give any details as to why.

As an aside, having data members be references makes your type harder to interoperate with. Just use pointers, then you can be default constructible

Hey  that's me! Look ma' I'm on TV!

a comment on my answer: "For posterity, note that the statement "The first fix is to make your iterator default constructible" is correct today, but is considered a bug in the standard and this requirement will be lifted eventually. See open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2325r3.html where the weakly_incrementable concept is discussed, and en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/weakly_incrementable"

The answers on the posts refered by 康桓瑋 do not completely answer the "why", but I added them as related.

@super As sbi already asked in a comment on an answer on the first post linked by 康桓瑋 I also wonder if the double pass guarantee can't be achieved using copy construction, which works well with const reference members.
